# KMS KeyPolicy for CloudTrail read/write and EventBridge read?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge, amazon-cloudtrail, amazon-kms

I have the following resources in a CDK project:

```python
from aws_cdk import (
  aws_cloudtrial as cloudtrail,
  aws_events as events,
  aws_events_targets as targets,
  aws_kms as kms
)

#Create a Customer-Managed Key (CMK) for encrypting the CloudTrail logs
mykey = kms.Key(self, "key", alias="somekey")

#Create a CloudTrail Trail, an S3 bucket, and a CloudWatch Log Group
trail = cloudtrail.Trail(self, "myct", send_to_cloud_watch_logs=True, management_events=cloudtrail.ReadWriteType.WRITE_ONLY)

#Create an EventBridge Rule to do something when certain events get matched in the CloudWatch Log Group
rule = events.Rule(self, "rule", event_pattern=events.eventPattern(
  #the contents of the eventPattern don't matter for this example
), targets= [ 
  #the contents of the targets don't matter either
])
```

The problem is, if I pass my key to the trail with the `encryption_key=mykey` parameter, CloudTrail complains that it can't use the key.

I've tried many different KMS policies, but other than making it wide open to the entire world, I can't figure out how to enable my CloudTrail Trail to read/write using the key (it has to put data into the S3 bucket), and allow CloudWatch and EventBridge to decrypt the encrypted data in the S3 bucket.

The documentation on this is very poor, and depending on which source I look at, they use different syntax and don't explain why they do things. Like, here's just one example from a CFT:

```yaml
Condition:
  StringLike:
    'kms:EncryptionContext:aws:cloudtrail:arn': !Sub 'arn:aws:cloudtrail:*:${AWS::AccountId}:trail/*'
```

OK, but what if I need to connect up EventBridge and CloudWatch Logs, too? No example, no mention of it, as if this use case doesn't exist.

If I omit the encryption key, everything works fine - but I do need the data encrypted at rest in S3, since it's capturing sensitive operations in my master payer account.

Is there any shorthand for this in CDK, or is there an example in CFT (or even outside of IaC tools entirely) of the proper key policy to use in this scenario?

I tried variations on `mykey.grant_decrypt(trail.log_group)`, `mykey.grant_encrypt_decrypt(trail)`, `mykey.grant_decrypt(rule)`, etc. and all of them throw an inscrutable stack trace saying something is undefined, so apparently those methods just don't work.

Comment: What is the error message? Is it a synth-time, deploy-time or run-time error?

Comment: Deploy-time. The error was essentially that CloudTrail couldn't access "either the s3 bucket or the KMS key". It couldn't tell me which one, but I was able to narrow it down to the KMS key because disabling encryption resulted in a successful deploy (so the bucket was fine). I since resolved the issue by manually creating this setup and copying the KMS key policy from the management console into my CDK script.